# Prove $\vdash (A_1 ↔ A_2) \vee (A_2 ↔ A_3) \vee (A_3 ↔ A_1) $ using natural deduction.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I think this is true. Because by the pigeon hole principle, Two of $A_1, A_2, A_3$  must have the same true value.  But I have no idea how to prove it.. Can somebody help me?

Of course, we can use well-known logical laws. For example De Morgan, law of the excluded middle..

Comment: You can not use DeMorgan to prove $\vdash$ (unless there is a rule in your natural deduction system that has the form of the DeMorgan law, which is usually not the case). $\vdash \phi$ means "$\phi$ is derivable in some formal system", e.g. natural deduction. The DeMorgan laws, on the other hand, are logical equivalences (statements of the form $\phi \equiv \psi$), which talk about truth under an assignment function. $\vdash$ is not the same as $\vDash$. If you are supposed to show $\vdash$, you have to use the rules of natural deduction.

Comment: @lemontree  Since we have already proved De Morgan  laws $\vdash  \neg (\alpha_1\vee \alpha_2)   ↔ \neg \alpha_1\wedge \neg \alpha_2$ for all wff $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$, I think we can use it without repeating the proof. So, I think If we got the proof of $\vdash  \neg (\alpha_1\vee \alpha_2)$, we can get $\vdash  \neg \alpha_1\wedge \neg \alpha_2$  by modus ponens. Of course, if we follow the definition of natural deduction rigorously, this is wrong, but if we do so, I think this proof seems very long... If I  misunderstand something, please let me know.

Comment: If you have the DeMorgan laws as derivable biimplications, sure, that works. I just thought you might be confusing syntax with semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof in a Fitch-style natural deduction proof:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Long comment*

I think that the proof is quite long: we can try with a simpler (but similar) example :

> $\vdash (A_1 \to A_2) \lor (A_2 \to A_3) \lor (A_3 \to A_1)$.

In this case, the proof is straightforward, using EM :

1) $\vdash A_1 \lor \lnot A_1$

2) $A_1$ --- assumed [a] for $\lor$-elim

3) $A_3 \to A_1$ --- from 2) by $\to$-intro

4) $(A_2 \to A_3) \lor (A_3 \to A_1)$ --- from 3) by $\lor$-intro

> 5) $(A_1 \to A_2) \lor (A_2 \to A_3) \lor (A_3 \to A_1)$ --- from 4) by $\lor$-intro

6) $\lnot A_1$ --- assumed [b] for $\lor$-elim

7) $A_1$ --- assumed [c]

8) $A_2$ --- from 6) and 7)

9) $A_1 \to A_2$ --- from 7) and 8) by $\to$-intro, discharging [c]

10) $(A_1 \to A_2) \lor (A_2 \to A_3)$ --- from 9) by $\lor$-intro

> 11) $(A_1 \to A_2) \lor (A_2 \to A_3) \lor (A_3 \to A_1)$ --- from 10) by $\lor$-intro

Now we can conclude by $\lor$-elim from 1), discharging [a] and [b].

Answer (score 1):

I think one can take advantage of the fact that the operators  <->  (biconditionnal)  and " w " ( X-OR, exclusive or )  are, so to say, the "negation" of each other , in the same manner as & and NAND ( Which can be checked using  truth tables).

---

I'll use the following facts ( which can  be proved with natural deduction, except maybe the first part of fact 1 , that is linked to the associativity of disjunction; this extremely basic fact might require a semantic method, I do not know).

(1) (AvBvC) is equivalent to (AvB)v C , which in turn is equivalent to
(~ (AvB) --> C )

(2) [ replacement rule ] from ~(A <--> B) infer ( AwB) , and reciprocally   ( with **" w" meaning " exclusive or"** )

(3) [ w elim 1 ]from (AwB) and A, infer ~B / from (AwB) and B, infer ~A

(4) [ w elim 2 ] from (AwB) and ~A infer B / from (AwB) and ~B infer A

(5)  [<-> Intro ] From (A --> B) and (B -->A) infer( A <--> B)   [  <-> Intro ]

**Strategy** :

Fact  (1) means that, in order to prove (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3) v (A3<->A1)

**we only have to prove that  :  ~  ( (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3) )  --> (A3<->A1)** , which makes of **conditional proof** a possible strategy.

**Proof** :

Now, suppose ( for conditional proof) that you have :

~  ( (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3) ).

By DeMorgan's law, infer from that :

~ (A1<->A2) &  ~ (A2<->A3).

Eliminate & to get

~ (A1<->A2)

~ (A2<->A3).

Use fact (2)  - that is :  ~ (A <->B) iff (AwB)   - to get :

(A1 w A2)

(A2 w A3)

Now, suppose ( for conditional proof inside our main conditional proof)  you have A1.

Using fact (3) infer from A1 that  : ~ A2. And, using fact (4), infer from ~ A2 that A3 is true. You have shown  that :

```
                               IF A1 THEN A3
```

In the same way, suppose ( for conditional proof, still inside the main conditional proof) that you have A3.

Using fact (3), infer that A2 is false. And using fact (4), infer from ~A2 that A1 is true. You have shown that :

```
                                  IF A3 THEN A1
```

Now , using the fact (5) ( that is <--> Intro)  infer from (A1 --> A3) and (A3 --> A1) that

```
                                     **A1 <--> A3**
```

Under our main assumption : ~  ( (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3) ), we have shown : A1 <--> A3.

**The conditional proof rule allows us to derive from this that** :

```
         ~  ( (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3) ) --> A1 <--> A3
```

But , **by fact (1) we know that this is equivalent to** :

```
            ( (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3) ) v  (A1 <--> A3)  ,
```

**and finally to our goal** :

```
               (A1<->A2) v (A2<->A3)  v  (A3 <--> A1)
```

( knowing that the <-> operator is commutative)